spring boot generation type sequence not working properly with postgresql
@Data
@Entity
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer id;
    private String questionTitle;
    private String option1;
    private String option2;
}

this is my dao.
every time when i post new data the id value is wrongly generated in postgresql.
I tried to delete the table. even also the table start with id not in sequence
I want the id to look in sequential order
